# FullCalendar AgendaWeek

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I'm working with FullCalendar ,i dipslaying a month view and when i click on an event the view changing for 'agenda week'.

```
    eventClick: function(event, jsEvent, view) {

  $("#callendar").fullCalendar('gotoDate', event.start.format('h:mm:ss a'));
   $("#calendar").fullCalendar('changeView', 'agendaWeek');


   $("#calendar").fullCalendar(  {

    eventSources: [
        {

         events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {

        $.ajax({
            url: 'calendar/get_passation',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {                
                idEvent: event.id
            },
            success: 'ok'

            });


    }
        }
    ],

    });
```

But on the agenda week view ,the hours of day wont appear 
see 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zT4cB.png)

Comment: This could be a style issue more than a fullcalendar issue. Did you apply style to your calendar ? Also i advice you not formatting the date when sending it with `gotoDate` as fullCalendar accepts Moment objects

Comment: I don't know if it's related to your issue (as Nenri says it sounds more like some accidental CSS conflict between fullCalendar's CSS and some other styles in your page - try removing custom CSS and see if it resolves it), but completely re-initialising the calendar within an event handler of the same calendar is probably not a good idea. It's also very inefficient. If you just want to add/change/delete/ an event source the use the functions provided - see the "methods" section at the bottom of this page: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-data e.g. addEventSource, removeEventSource etc.

Comment: can you place you full js code i dont see plugin used